# How can I do so that Symfony don't clear SESSION in the end of execution?

Tags: php, session, symfony, ckfinder

My problem is that Symfony after end of execution remove all internal values from SESSION, so `session_id` is the same, but values of session is empty, and I can't get it with CKFinder.

I need to allow Symfony don't clear session after execution for use session value in CKFinder. My goal is to secure CKFinder for a way, that I try in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22764832/how-to-include-ckfinder2-to-the-php-page-with-session-security) question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Symfony don't clear SESSION in the end of execution. Session handle with `NativeFileSessionHandler` and save it in the `app/cache/env/sessions` directory.

For more information, you can see in [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/session_configuration.html)